# How to skip or ignore rows above header?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, rows

```
Title: This is parsed file      
Job: Proj Doom

Flow,Value  
102,2   
103,3   
104,4   
105,5   
106,6
```

I am new here and to D3. My d3 graph works fine if I take the above csv and remove everything above the header. The csv is produced after a test and I can't go thru every file and remove the rows above the header before loading to D3 graph.
I would like to grab this files and visualize it without modifying it.

So, my only issue is how to filter out the top 5 rows. The number of rows above the header is the same among all the *.csv produced, the contents might change.

Can it be done within the `d3.csv("myCsv", type, function(){});`? Or it needs to be done before with js? I'm using d3 v4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem of using a `type` function, better known as `row` function, is that it will be called for all rows. That's not what you want.

Probably the best idea here is loading that CSV as plain text. In v5:

```
d3.text("data.csv").then(function(data){
```

And in v4:

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(data){
```

... and then we remove the first rows. Here, I'm removing the first 3 rows:

```
const filtered = data.split('\n').slice(3);
```

Then, we recreate the CSV file:

```
const newCSV = filtered.join('\n');
```

And finally we parse it:

```
const newData = d3.csvParse(newCSV);
```

By the way, `d3.csvParse` works both on v4 and v5.

Of course, all this can be done in just 1 line:

```
data = d3.csvParse(data.split('\n').slice(3).join('\n'))
```

Here is a bl.ocks showing it (using v5): https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/5a43fdcedc214ecdb2eb20ac91af8623/6473eb3dfb05361a3dd7972756a490d9885542f5

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I used the v4 version of the d3.text() along with the 1-liner in place of the d3.csv() function. Now I am able to set the slice() to '0' and it works with normal csv then set to '5' to deal my out-of-the-ordinary csv. Thank you.